# "Let A be a set. We are able to quotient all possible well-orders over the set A." What does this mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

"Let A be a set. We are able to quotient all possible well-orders over the set A."

This was the first line in the set-up of some exercises I have to do (which ask specific questions depending on whether the set A is finite or infinite).

However, I have no idea what it actually means by "quotient all possible well-orders".

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain this! Thanks.

Thanks for the guidance! I'm pretty sure it makes sense now.

Comment: Why don't you write a bit more of what the exercises say, and it may be easier to answer from that context. Just with what is written, I can think of two possible interpretations.

Comment: This sounds like a sloppy formulation of the beginning of a proof of Hartogs's theorem. If so, it should read "We can form the quotient of the set of all well-orders of $A$ by the equivalence relation of order-isomorphism."  Does that make more sense in your context?  (If not, show us some of the context.)

Comment: Andreas's formulation seems appropriate. You may want to check whether you are looking at well-orderings of the whole set $A$, or just of some subset of $A$.

Comment: Thanks Andres. My friend said that our teacher had made the comment like: 
"those well orders whose fields are a subset of A; where the field of a well order is just the set of elements related by it". 
When referring to the line about the quotient in class.

Comment: So! What I'm thinking is this:
I consider all the possible subsets of the set A.
Then I consider all possible well orders over these subsets. 
Then, the collection of all sets of well orders, where each set of well orders come from a different subset of A, can be partitioned based on an equivalence relation of order isomorphism. Is that correct?